# Load testing for applications invoking nodejs sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, selenium, jmeter, load

I want to test an application which uses node js sockets with a maximum number of the load.

**Application Insight :** It has a page which shows how many user are currently using that page also there are cells where if one user clicks to edit it will be blocked by other users. These two functionalities open a node js socket to communicate. And the socket is only opened when the page is loaded successfully (javascript on ready document)

**My Trial :** I tried JMeter for applying the load (simultaneous users), but through JMeter, the application is unable to open the nodejs sockets. Currently, am using selenium to open different tabs of browser and manually checking the resource consumption on the server. But the problem is I can't open more than 10 tabs on a machine as the browser itself consumes memory.

I don't want to test nodejs sockets to open by JMeter (or any other tools) as I want the application to do that.

Any suggestions/guidance or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**
>
> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript** found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time)

So JMeter won't invoke JavaScript on page load, you will have to simulate the associated requests manually. The options are in

- Get yourself a more powerful machine or consider using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) plugin along with [JMeter Distributed](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) testing. You can also try using [LoadRunner TruClient](https://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/TruClient-in-the-world-of-Load-Testing/ba-p/5927581) as an alternative, but it is also very resource intensive, it has license fees as well
- Use [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) to simulate JavaScript-driven calls. See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide for more details on plugin installation and usage. You should be able to get total time of main page request and WebSocket Sampler(s) execution using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure Websocket is used by your application, I would suggest using a Websocket plugin, there are 2 implementations which deserve attention:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers
- https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/cloud-based-jmeter-websocket-testing/

The problem and complexity will be that you cannot record those with JMeter Test Script recorder, so you will have to manually reproduce the queries.

Another option is to use WebDriver Sampler and combine it with Cloud technology as it is very resource intensive. In this case look at this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/scaling-easily-jmeter-webdriver-using-aws-cloud-with-redline13/